# The same computer, why is Debian more laggy than Ubuntu?

Tags: debian, ubuntu

Yesterday, I installed Ubuntu 22.04 and it worked well, I didn't even feel any lag in it. Today I wanted to try Debian 11 and I did so. My Debian system only ran for half an hour, and it froze, and I only have to force restart. No other software was installed, I just opened firefox software. My computer does not have a  graphics card either, the CPU is AMD R7-4800u. What is the reason for this phenomenon, I downloaded both software from official channels.

Now, the screen shows:

```
Ｃheck your video drivers
Your system is currently running without video hardware acceleation.
You may experience poor performance and high CPU usage.
```

I tried a lot of ways to install drivers but I didn't know which one is right. So it is easy to freeze.

Thanks.

Comment: Debian only supplies free drivers with its official distribution.  You need to opt-into using non-free.  Ubuntu supplies non-free drivers by default.  This is probably the difference.   What video-chip is used? `lspci | grep VGA`.  Even if you don't have a full-blown video-card, you'll have something other than your CPU.

Comment: @Stewart  Hello, I tried as you instructed.  The result is: `00:0f.0 VGA compatible controller: VMware SVGA II Adapter` as I installed the Debian in VMware.

Comment: VMware is proprietary software, so this could by why its hardware enumation is not handled well by a vanilla Debian install.  If VMware supplies "guest additions", that is what you should install to mod your system to handle its proprietary emulated hardware.

Comment: @Stewart The Ubuntu I installed was also in the VMware software, which ran rightly. How should I modify my VMware. May you send me some links? Thanks.